# How to add Preference in ICS

Tags: android

I need to add Preference in `ICS` using `addPreferencesFromResource()`.
It is shown as deprecated in `ICS`.
I've added a preference layout in xml folder but this could not be added to the Preference activity.

How can I add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On API Level 11 and higher, the plan is for you to use `PreferenceFragments` to call `addPreferencesFromResource()`. You can see an example of this in [the documentation for `PreferenceActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html).

If you are trying to support `PreferenceFragment` on API Level 11+, yet still support older devices, you will need to do both the stuff shown in that documentation *and* call `addPreferencesFromResource()` directly in your `PreferenceActivity`... but only when you are on an older device. Even though `addPreferencesFromResource()` is marked as deprecated, that does not mean that it does not work, and more importantly *it is your only option* on API Level 10 and below.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Prefs/FragmentsBC) where I demonstrate supporting both API Level 11-style fragments and the classic `PreferenceActivity` from a single set of source.